# Time complexity for getting the list of keys in a hash table?

Tags: performance, hash, hashmap, hashtable, time-complexity

In a lot of languages you have the ability to get the list of keys from a hash table. Like the keySet() method for hash maps in java. How can this be obtained from a populated hash map? Isn't the hashfuction irreversible? Do you have too keep the keys in a separate list?

So when i use functions to obtain the list of keyes used in a populated hash table what is the time complexity of that function?

For my particular problem i happen to know the maximum number of entries in the hash table. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtually every hash table stores the keys in addition to the values. This is *necessary* anyway, to resolve hash collisions (in some cases collisions are provably impossible, but this requires enumerating the full key set beforehand so it doesn't apply to general-purpose hash table). That is, the hash table `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}` does not look like this:

```
1
2
```

but rather like this

```
("foo", 1)
("bar", 2)
```

Iterating over the keys is then simply a matter of iterating over the underlying structure of the hash table.

Comment: So it will take time proportional to the number of entry's in the table?

Comment: @HenrikSommerland Yes. It has to, even if it could conjure the keys out of nothing in constant time it would still have to do so n times. A more precise bound is the number of buckets in the array (which can be different in open adressing) -- but since that number should be at most a small constant multiple of the number of entries (e.g. to avoid wasting space), it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

In any reasonable implementation, touching all the keys in natural order (not sorted) is O(current size of the table including empty slots).

In an implementation that chains together the entries (e.g. Java as you can observe in [the LinkedHashMap iterator code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#LinkedHashMap.LinkedHashIterator)), the table size is irrelevant.  The algorithm is traversing a linked list.

You don't need to know the hash keys because the iterations are touching the data structure directly, not using the keys.

Comment: So the list of keyes is maintained during the population of the list or are they resolved afterwards?